# libCurl to download folder recursively from a http location which lists the directories and files. where a directory contains index.html

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am trying to use libcurl to download all the directories and file recursively.
Its downloading properly. But in one case where a directory contains index.html, its not able to download.
suppose: http://localhost:8080/
has following listing
001-Dir
    contains 001-dir-file.file
002-Dir
    contains index.html
    contains 003-Dir
           contains 003-dir-file.file

In this case it fails to download 002-Dir.
Note: we use the url http://localhhost:8080/001-Dir/ to download and read the tag  to know the contents of that dir.
But where the directory already has an index. html, above url returns the contents of that index.html instead of the listing of contents.

Could any one please help me what setting in need to do in libcurl to avoid above issue.

My current curl_easy_setopt settings in c++ code are as below
CURLOPT_URL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION

Comment: `"But where the directory already has an index. html, above url returns the contents of that index.html instead of the listing of contents."` This is controlled by the web server, not libcurl.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, for understanding my problem exactly.
Is there some settings I can do from wget / libcurl / from the server side so that existing index.html content will not be returned automatically?
Thank You

Comment: You'd have to change the web server's settings. curl/wget/etc. have no control over it.